# Package in Android

Tags: java, android, package

```
The declared package "com.google.zxing.common" does not match the expected package "zxing.
```

I get this message. I created a package called "Zxing" and in each class there is a error message stating the above message. I can't run my app until this is resolved. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you import the jar and made sure that it's part of the libs folder?

Answer (score 1):

You have one or more classes, with:

`package com.google.zxing.commmon`

that do not reside in `src/com/google/zxing/common/`, but instead reside in `src/zxing/`.